# If I plug a hibernated hard-drive to another laptop, what will happen to the hibernated hard-drive?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, external-hard-drive, hibernate

This is nothing too tech-savvy like mounting...

If I do these things:

1. Put my laptop into "hibernate" state instead of shutting it down
2. Open the back of the laptop (I mean something [like this](http://www.ehow.com/how_6154413_remove-back-laptop.html))
3. Pull out the hard-drive from the back
4. Put the hard-drive into an external hard-drive casing, something like this:
   [image]
5. Plug the hard-drive into another laptop via USB, just like plugging in USB hard-drive. Like this:
   [image]

What would happen to the hibernated hard-drive?

- Would this procedure damage the hard-drive in any way (since it is still "hibernate" state)?
- Would the laptop (another laptop) read the data inside the hard-drive?
- Would it be safe to use the hard-drive as an external hard-drive in the long run (in case the original laptop is broken)?

I hope I lay out my question/explanation clear, since English is not my mother tounge. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No damage would occur; the hibernated drive would be perfectly readable, and safe to use for however long you like.

Deleting the hibernation state file (\hiberfil.sys on a Windows drive) would make it impossible to restore from hibernation if you ever put the drive back in its original laptop; you'd have to boot up like any other time you start up the machine from power off. That's the worst you can do to it, though.

Comment: Correct.  When Windows hibernates, it writes the contents of memory to the hiberfil.sys file.  So, when the computer boots off of that drive, it reads the hiberfil.sys contents back into memory.  However, changes to the contents of that drive could potentially break resuming from a hibernated state.  Worst cast, Windows would throw an error and you would lose your ability to resume, but you would be able to boot normally from the original laptop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The other answer mentions something about covering hard drive hole. It reminds me: is there something to be take in caution during the process I outlined above?

Comment: @deathlock The label on the top of the hard disk will probably say something like "Do not cover this hole" or "Do not cover any drive holes". Said holes allow air pressure equalization between the hard disk's interior and the surrounding environment; covering them results in a _head crash_ -- the unrecoverable destruction of the physical media on the hard disk platters. You'll be fine as long as no part of the the external enclosure forms an airtight seal over any hole on the top cover of the hard disk, something which is highly unlikely to occur in practice.

Comment: @deathlock The only other caution I'd recommend is to avoid dropping the hard drive or subjecting it to similar abuse. Other than that, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes no damage will occur. But be careful. You have to choose correct casing for your hard drive. Wrong casing will cover hard drive hole which used for cooling. If it happen your hard drive will be failure and all data be lost. This happen to me so careful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Regarding covering the hole, is there anything that might cause accidental covering? And where exactly is the hole you mentioned above?

Comment: @dipa The holes are not for cooling; they allow air pressure equalization between the HDA and the external atmosphere, which is necessary to prevent head crash.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernating an external drive is the WORST thing you can do if you going back and forth between multiple computers.
Many laptops and desktops actually hibernate when shutting down, so they can start up faster next time which is good, except when using an external drive.
this creates a significant problem for people who use a common drive to go between machines when the hibernating drives, when files are created or moved to EXISTING folders there is no issues
when files are created or moved to NEW folders there is a HUGE Problem,  as when windows is shutdown(and actually hibernates the file system changes is not written to the external drive) so when plugged into another computer the files are gone and new  folders appear empty, even though the drive is showing the space is used, it's not there,  if you plug them into the original computer they show up again
another issue is if this created "dirty" drive is plugged into the second computer windows wants to scan and fix the drive which will erase this data that was not written to the drive on the original computer

so don't do this, and turn off the power settings to make the pc actually shutdown and not hibernate, or yank the drive BEFORE shutting down, as long as drive is set up to not have to be safely removed

Answer (score -1):

It will be broken beyond repair. Definitely you won't be able to use it in long-term. Make sure you have a proper backup before proceeding.

Comment: Not true in any way or form

Comment: My hdd was broken from this.

Comment: then you damaged it in some other way.  the method described by the poster is perfectly safe.